# PHP PDO UPDATE table not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the PHP PDO's to insert and update values in a table.
The insertion works fine. But when i try to update, nothing happens.
I get no errors, no exceptions.

the code is

```
   $sql="UPDATE customers SET Name=:name,Company=:company,Address=:address,City=:city,State=:state,Country=:country,MainP=:phonem,CellP=:phonec,Email=:email,Action=:action WHERE CompanyID=:cid";
```

and the rest:

```
               $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                 $stmt->bindParam(":name",$name);
                $stmt->bindParam(":company",$company);
                $stmt->bindParam(":cid",$customer_id);
                $stmt->bindParam(":address",$address);
                $stmt->bindParam(":city",$city);
                $stmt->bindParam(":state",$state);
                $stmt->bindParam(":country",$country);
                $stmt->bindParam(":phonem",$main_num);
                $stmt->bindParam(":phonec",$cell_num);
                $stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindParam(":action",$action);
            $stmt->execute();
           echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

So, is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that i am getting a row count of 0. And I've tried without the quotes. It still doesnt work

EDIT: Just found out that customer_id is being returned as 0 froma nother function.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you looked at whether there really is an error (return code of the execute statement) and if there is an error, what the details of that are? PDO::errorInfo() is of great help there.

Comment: yes. there are no exceptions. and the query works if i replace :cid with some valid ID

Comment: So, did you verify $customer_id contains the right value? What if you replace $customer_id with some valid ID?

Comment: Are you certain that `$customer_id` even contains a value? And is defined in that piece of code where you try to access it?

Comment: yes. i tried echoing it. and it does have a valid value

Comment: thanks a lot. i checked again and found that the customer_id is actually 0. it was returning perfectly at first. but now i know that it's the problem with customer_id. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is no data that query can update ,when using strings like name in query ,try giving like & % to be safe(there may be empty spaces if not taken care off while inseting)

example

```
WHERE Name like '%name%";
```

Comment: I'm checking with CompanyID, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: try putting actual strings instead of variables to cross varify you are syntactically correct

Comment: $sql =UPDATE customers SET Name = ?, WHERE Name = ?";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($name,$name));

Comment: Try with question mark place holder

$sql =UPDATE customers SET Name = ?, WHERE Name = ?";
$sth->bindParam(1, $name );
$sth->bindParam(2, $name);

Answer (score 3):

Take the quotes out, field = :field

```
$sql="UPDATE customers SET Name = :name, Company = :company, Address  = :address, City = :city, State= :state, Country = :country, MainP = :phonem, CellP = :phonec, Email = :email, Action = :action WHERE Name = :name";
```

Also, Action may be protected, you may need to wrap it in ``

Finally, you're setting the name to the same value as your where clause which is bad, use a primary key.

Two reasons, one, it won't ever update the row you hoped, second, if someone else had that name you'd update their row's other values.

Comment: I have tried without the quotes and also changed the checking variable to CompanyID. Still no luck

Comment: `action` is NOT a reserved word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Good, wasn't sure didn't go check. "may be"

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need the single quotes around the PDO variables (Examples - :name, :company, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The query fails because you are updating by `:name` value, which is actually the new value you are trying to set. So no rows are found in order to be updated.
To fix that you need to change the where clause and use `:old_name`.

Also, I recommend to use Primary Keys and numbers if available instead of the field `name`.

Comment: sorry about that. i am using CompanyID=:cid now and it is still not working. Still, the row count is 0. and the company id is unique and kept constant.